# How to use pytest `request.config` inside the django.test.TestCase class setUp function

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I am using pytest in my django project. I used pytest.config previously to get conftest.py values into the setUp function but it is deprecated since version 4.1. In the [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#pytest-config-global) they suggest to use `request` fixture to get configs but I couldn't find a proper way get configs inside to the TestCase class using request fixture. Following code sample is the working code which uses the pytest.config. Any way to get configs without getting **PytestDeprecationWarning**  will be helpful.

```
import pytest
from django.conf import settings
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.utils import override_settings

@override_settings(USE_SUBDOMAIN=False, PRODUCTION_DOMAIN='example.com')
class TestSample(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['test_data']

    def setUp(self):
        url_base = '{scheme}://{domain}/sample'.format(
          scheme=pytest.config.option.url_scheme,
          domain=settings.PRODUCTION_DOMAIN,
        )
```